# How to get "sum" of a column with a condition in Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, postgresql, django-models

I am using django 1.11 and postgresql 9.5.
In a view, I am reading a file and inserting data to DB.

The table structure is like this..

```
 id           | integer                  
 user_id      | integer  
 percentage   | numeric(3,2)
```

After inserting data, I have table like this.,

```
id  user_id percentage
1   1       9
2   1       50
3   1       4
4   2       12
5   2       23
6   3       46
7   3       33  
8   4       87
```

Now I want to find, sum of percentage of each user, like,

```
user-1 = 63
user-2 = 35
user-3 = 79
user-4 = 87
```

I went through the documents, and I found aggregation query like,

```
<modelname>.objects.aggregate(Sum('percentage'))
```

but, this will give sum of whole column, I want sum for individual user. How to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need use annotate

```
<modelname>.objects.values('user').annotate(percentage=Sum('percentage')).order_by()
```